# Django low query speed for "checking if OneToOneField is None"

Tags: django, django-models

My model is like this:

```
class ArticleText(models.Model):
    article = models.OneToOneField(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="article_text")
    text = models.TextField()
    indexed_by_es = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)
    indexed_by_solr = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)
```

`Article` is an original model, and I want to use `ArticleText` to extend it.

And the time consuming code is this:

```
articles = Article.objects.filter(Q(article_text=None))[0:10]
```

There are about 10,000 articles in my database. How can I make this query faster?

Comment: How do you check whether it is `None`? If you do this in Django, itself, then each time you will *make* a request. Check `article_id` instead. Anyway, please provide *how* you check it right now (or give some context what you aim to do).

Comment: Sorry... ...  I accidentally posted the question before I finished it... I will repost it later QAQ

Comment: What query does this generate? Can you print the result of `str(Article.objects.filter(Q(article_text=None))[0:10].query)`.

Comment: It generates this: `SELECT main_article.id, main_article.section_id, main_article.title, main_article.publish_time, main_article.image1_url, main_article.image2_url, main_article.image3_url, main_article.content FROM main_article LEFT OUTER JOIN external_data_access_articletext ON (main_article.id = external_data_access_articletext.article_id) WHERE external_data_access_articletext.id IS NULL LIMIT 10`. (`main` and `external_data_access` are both Django apps)

Comment: Seems like the outer join is the cause...

Answer (score 0):

## Updated

Thanks for @Sachin Kukreja.

Use `articles = Article.objects.filter(article_text=None).values('id')[0:10]` can prevent the raw SQL to select too many useless fields.It does what my previous answer does, but in a neat way.

---

## Previous Answer

Thanks for @Willem Van Onsem's comment, I notice where this issue comes from: the query generated by Django selects too many useless fields. So I build a raw query myself:

`articles = Article.objects.raw('''
   select a.id from main_article as a 
   left outer join external_data_access_articletext as b
   on a.id = b.article_id
   where (b.id is null) or (b.indexed_by_es = false) 
   limit 10''')`

It is faster. Think this might be a bug for Django.

Comment: You could have chained `.values('id')` method call on your filter query.